Spring Boot Scheduler is calling a method multiple times
I want to schedule some tasks in my Spring Boot application.
But the problem is that my app is hosted on multiple instances (let's say 2), so this function is being called 2 times every 5 minutes. But I want to make sure that it is called only once every 5 minutes.
How can I achieve this?
I tried the following:
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 300000) // Every 5 minutes
public void performTask() {
    System.out.println("Task executed at: " + new java.util.Date());
}

